# Charting a List - with defined Y Column

Tags: sharepoint-2007, web-parts, mschart

I am using the ChartPart control to graph out information.

Problem i am having, and seems to be in the list, i think.  The X-value (vertical data) is represented correctly but the Y-value (horizontal data) is not being represented right.

X-value range: 0 to 800000 (actual)
Y-value range:
  (current) 0 to 3
  (should be) 0, 4, 5, 6

If anyone has any ideas i would be greatly appreciative.  this is the same chartpart control from [codeplex.com](http://chartpart.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

How do you mean x vertical and y horisontal?
It's otherway around...
Anyway I would check your settings once again... seems like a definiton problem.

Comment: Actually for most graphs it is X is horizontal and Y is for Vertical but when plotting on the MSCharts this charpart for a couple of them uses X for the vertical and Y for the horizontal.